# Azure Durable Function to persist state?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-durable-functions

I am trying to implement the following task:

- If the action has not successfully performed in the past 24 hours, perform the action store the result (success/failure, and the time)
- Repeat in 15 minutes (eternally)

Ideally, I don't want to use an external storage (cost saving) since all I need to store is a string in between runs. However, I do need to have guarantee that the state (returned string from each run) is persisted between runs.

I have 2 questions:

1. Do Azure Durable functions suitable for this task?
2. If no, what are my alternatives?
3. If yes, does below code do the trick (in the "right" way)?

.

```
[FunctionName("MyOrchestratorFunction")]
public static async Task<string> RunOrchestrator(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    // Get the state from the context
    string state = "some intitial value";

    // Perform some action
    string result = await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("MyActivityFunction", state);

    // Store the result in the state
    state = result;

    // Wait for 15 minutes
    await context.CreateTimer(context.CurrentUtcDateTime.AddMinutes(15), CancellationToken.None);

    // Call the orchestrator function again with the updated state
    return await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("MyOrchestratorFunction", state);
}

[FunctionName("MyActivityFunction")]
public static string RunActivity(
    [ActivityTrigger] string state)
{
    // Perform some action using the state

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I tried this [code](https://i.imgur.com/lzB4YDV.png) got this [output](https://i.imgur.com/s91kDSH.png) after 15 min it will [fail](https://i.imgur.com/Do93X8j.png) after rerunning it run [again](https://i.imgur.com/cizBupf.png)

Comment: [Eternal Orchestrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-eternal-orchestrations?tabs=csharp) might be what you're looking for. I have also successfully used [Durable Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-entities?tabs=csharp) to store small amounts of state which can be used throughout a workflow.

Comment: @phil I am actually looking at Durable Entities but having a hard time to get a working example from documentation. Do you have a working example somewhere I can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Answering havij's second question about Durable Entities:

**Entity Function OrchestrationData.cs**

```cs
public class OrchestrationData : IOrchestrationData
{
    [JsonProperty("orchestrationId")]
    public string OrchestrationId { get; set; }

    public void SetOrchestrationId(string orchestrationId)
    {
        OrchestrationId = orchestrationId;
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(OrchestrationData))]
    public static Task Run([EntityTrigger] IDurableEntityContext context)
        => context.DispatchAsync<OrchestrationData>();
}
```

**Orchestrator**

```cs
...
    EntityId entityId = new EntityId(nameof(OrchestrationData),
    IOrchestrationData proxy = context.CreateEntityProxy<IOrchestrationData>(entityId);
    proxy.SetOrchestrationId("a1b2c3");
...
```

Be careful that your state properties are proper serializable objects. I had problems with arrays of primitives like `string[]`.